# How to get count of globalOnly FacesMessages better?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I write a "not so correct" code to count the globalOnly messages programatically.

```
for (final FacesMessage message : facesContext.getMessageList()) {
    if (!message.getClass().getCanonicalName().equals("javax.faces.component.MessageFactory.BindingFacesMessage")) {
            globalOnlyMessagesCount++;
    }
}
```

For non-jsf developres: `javax.faces.component.MessageFactory.BindingFacesMessage` is a non-visible class, so instanceof doesn't work. As I found the message is a `BindingFacesMessage` or `FacesMessage`

Is there any **better** solution? (except I put the string literal to constant).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Global only messages are identified by a `null` client ID.

So, this should do, in combination with [another getter taking a client ID](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getMessageList%28java.lang.String%29):

```
int globalOnlyMessagesCount = facesContext.getMessageList(null).size();
```